# While writing a string in a csv file, how to avoid duplicate string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I successfully wrote a script by Python3 with bs4 to get strings without duplicates from a Wikipedia page. For that,

The Algorithm:

1) Writing csv file **with** duplicates

with the above file,

2) Writing csv file **without** duplicates.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://ta.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=அட்டவணை:அ. மருதகாசி-பாடல்கள்.pdf&action=history'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
#getting the uncleaned contributors
userBdi = soup.findAll('bdi')
#list 2 string
uncleanedContributors =''.join(str(userBdi)[1:-1]).replace('</','<').replace('<bdi>','').replace(',','\n').replace(' ','').replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு').replace('Bot','').replace('BOT','')
print()
print('The output of uncleaned contributors')
print('--------------------------------------')
print(uncleanedContributors)
with open('uncleaned-contributors.csv','a') as csvwrite:
    csvwriter = csvwrite.write(uncleanedContributors+'\n')

content = open('uncleaned-contributors.csv','r').readlines()
content4set = set(content)
cleanedcontent = open('cleaned-contributors.csv','w')
print()
print('The output of cleaned contributors')
print('--------------------------------------')
for i, line in enumerate(content4set,0):
    cleanedcontent.write("{}.{}".format(str(i+1),line.replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு')))
    line=line.strip()
    print(i, line)
cleanedcontent.close()
```

How can I directly write a CSV file without duplicates? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve your problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import csv 

url = 'https://ta.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=அட்டவணை:அ. மருதகாசி-பாடல்கள்.pdf&action=history'
content = requests.get(url).content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 
#getting the uncleaned contributors 
userBdi = soup.findAll('bdi') 
#list 2 string 
uncleanedContributors =''.join(str(userBdi)[1:-1]).replace('</','<').replace('<bdi>','').replace(',','\n').replace(' ','').replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு').replace('Bot','').replace('BOT','') 

cleanedcontent = open('cleaned-contributors.csv','w') 
print() 
print('The output of cleaned contributors') 
print('--------------------------------------') 
def unique_list(l):
    ulist = []
    [ulist.append(x) for x in l if x not in ulist]
    return ulist
a = ' '.join(unique_list(uncleanedContributors.split()))

for  i, j in enumerate(a.split(' ')):
    cleanedcontent.write("{}.{}".format(str(i+1),j.replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு')))
    cleanedcontent.write('\n')
    print(i+1, j)

cleanedcontent.close()
```

On execution,

```
[1]: 
The output of cleaned contributors
--------------------------------------
1 Balajijagadesh
2 Info-farmer 
3 Tshrinivasan
```

The above solution code gave the exact output you had desired in the problem and was able to directly write to a CSV file without any duplicates.

Comment: The output file's serial number starts from 1, 2, 3 as i wish but the terminal says 0,1,2. Is it possible to change the number in terminal?

Comment: i+1. nice. Will you pls explain, why it differs? I want to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `for` loop  iterations by default are indexed at zero.... in Python